# UnknownFormat in Devise::SessionsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails 4 app (that was upgraded from Rails 3) in which I decided to delete one of the controllers. I then moved the methods from that deleted controller to the ApplicationController, which included `before_filter :authenticate_user!`

Here's what my ApplicationController looks like now:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :json

  def index
    gon.rabl

    @user = current_user
    gon.rabl "app/views/users/show.json.rabl", as: "current_user"
  end

  def markdown
    require 'redcarpet'
    renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new
    extensions = {}
    Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)
  end

  helper_method :markdown

end
```

Now, I'm getting this error:

`ActionController::UnknownFormat in Devise::SessionsController#new`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might be due to the fact that you have set your application controller to respond only to json. If your Devise Controller inherits from ApplicationController (I think this is the default), then it will expect to see a content-type: json header, or your urls must all end in .json

Comment: You were totally right, but I'm confused because I set the previous controller (the one I deleted) to respond only to json and it worked fine with `before_filter :authenticate_user!`

Comment: Basically, all controllers (usually) inherit from the application controller, so if it is set to respond to json, then they all are. The devise controllers do not work (without some changes) unless they respond to html also

Comment: Is there some way to include the `respond_to :json` bit? Something like `respond_to :json, :unless => :devise_controller?` (which I just tried but doesn't work)

Comment: Have a separate controller! I think this is the best way even if you are making a single page application. Alternatively you can specify the content types per controller action, have a look at [this page](http://davidwparker.com/2010/03/09/api-in-rails-respond-to-and-respond-with/) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have the index method defined in application_controller. You should move it to the appropriate controller. If this is something you want to do before every action you might want to try something like this:

```
before_action :gon_user, only: :index
private
def gon_user
  gon.rabl

  @user = current_user
  gon.rabl "app/views/users/show.json.rabl", as: "current_user"
end
```

Though i've to be honest that i'm not sure about the gon stuff, can't remember if it was for moving data from ruby to javascript or for responding to ajax/json request.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've got the app organized this way because it's a single page web app using Backbone. `views/application/index.html.erb` contains the single point of entry for the whole app. The actual root is defined in the Backbone App object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Slicedpan. Got me thinking about a

```
respond_to :json
```

Used in my Rails Application as an API with Angular. As in my Rails controllers I use for requests from my Angular Services.

```
respond_with
```

In my case I ended up adding html to the respond_to:

```
respond_to :json, :html
```

The Default Mime Types can be seen here: 
http://apidock.com/rails/Mime